# Two Set contain same elements but they are not equal. Why that result?

Tags: java, collections, hashset

I try to check two set and I need both result are TRUE but they are not.
I don't know why one of result is return false.
Please help me, many thanks.

class CollectionExample:

```
    Set<String> set1 = new HashSet<>();
    set1.add(new String("A"));
    set1.add(new String("B"));
    Set<String> set2 = new HashSet<>();
    set2.add("A");
    set2.add("B");

    System.out.println("set1.equal(set2): "+ set1.equals(set2));

    Set<Person1> set3 = new HashSet<>();
    set3.add(new Person1("A", "1"));
    set3.add(new Person1("B", "1"));
    Set<Person1> set4 = new HashSet<>();
    set4.add(new Person1("A", "1"));
    set4.add(new Person1("B", "1"));

    System.out.println("set3.equal(set4): "+ set3.equals(set4));
```

entity Person1:

```
public class Person1 {

String firstName;
String lastName;

public Person1(String firstName, String lastName) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String firstName() { return firstName;}
public String lastName() { return lastName;}
}
```

Result:

```
set1.equal(set2): true
set3.equal(set4): false
```

Comment: Consider overriding `hashcode()` and `equals()` in your `Person` class. By default they are considered equal only if both are references to the same object.

Comment: Make it a habit to override `hashcode()` and `equals()` function for classes you write.

Comment: @Berger thanks. Its work.

Comment: @quazar thanks. Its work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override `equals()` and `hashCode()` in your `Person` class. Them implementation of `HashSet` uses those to determine if two `Person` instances are equal; if you don't override them then you'll get the default `Object` implementation in which two `Person` instances are equal only if they are the exact same reference.

Comment: Thanks. I try refer to same reference as below and without modify Person class. It return exactly same your answer, thanks.
`Person1 p1[] = {
    new Person1("A", "1"),
    new Person1("A", "2")
  };
  
  Set<Person1> set5 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(p1));
  Set<Person1> set6 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(p1));
  System.out.println("set5.equal(set6): "+ set5.equals(set6));`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not because of the comparison of `Set` but that of the `Person` class.

> If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then
>   calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce
>   the same integer result.
>
> But it is not necessary that if two objects have same `hashcode()`
>   then the two objects are `equals()` as well.

Even if the computed `hashcode()` is the same, the objects are not `equals()`.
This is because the `equals()` method inherited from the `Object` class compares the reference as well. Hence the output.